# Example aggregates kendo ui

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a problem with "aggregate kendo ui" my problem is the following I have several data that I bring from my SP which are repeated but that does not mean that all the data is the same an example:

[image]

What I would like to do with the aggregate `kendo-ui` would be to join it, all the names for example `YAUYOS` as it appears in the example in only one line but of course the other add it up and when I want to deploy it appears as in the example of the image. Here I leave a link of what was advancing.

http://dojo.telerik.com/AvAPOc

I would appreciate it if you could give me a clue how to do it, Regards.

Comment: First of all, as I understand you're using a Kendo UI Grid, not "aggregate kendo ui". Is that right?
How exactly do you want your grid to look?

Comment: Hi, how would you like it to be that all the data as it appreciates in the image this sumandos in a line instead of the 5 registers that are seen by separated and when I deploy that row with the summed data I appear the 5 registers that See in the picture. Thanks in advance!